# Open a .NET WPF window or Windows Form from VBA code

Tags: .net, vba

Can anyone give me the syntax required to call
a .NET assembly from VBA code.

I want to open a WPF window or Windows form from
an Access form.

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have control of the assembly

I want o be able to deploy the assembly to a file share
and have the VBA clients load it.

I thought that using a COM Interop would be best????

Malcolm

Comment: If you load it to a file share, you may have to deal with code security. I know that you can change the permissions of the share to allow the assembly to run. Or you could have the VBA copy the assembly to a "safe" place.  I would personally use the copy option.